# Obtaining DOCTYPE details using SAX (JDK 7)

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I'm using the SAX parser that comes with JDK7. I'm trying to get hold of the DOCTYPE declaration, but none of the methods in `DefaultHandler` seem to be fired for it. What am I missing?

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class Problem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head></head><body></body></html>";
        SAXParser saxParser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
        InputSource in = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        saxParser.parse(in, new DefaultHandler() {

            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println("Element: " + qName);
            }
        });;
    }
}
```

This produces:

```
Element: html
Element: head
Element: body
```

I *want* it to produce:

```
DocType: HTML
Element: html
Element: head
Element: body
```

How do I get the DocType?

---

Update: Looks like there's a `DefaultHandler2` class to extend. Can I use that as a drop-in replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a [DefaultHander](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html), use [org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ext/DefaultHandler2.html) which has the [startDTD()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ext/DefaultHandler2.html#startDTD%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

> Report the start of DTD declarations, if any. This method is intended
>   to report the beginning of the DOCTYPE declaration; if the document
>   has no DOCTYPE declaration, this method will not be invoked.
>
> All declarations reported through DTDHandler or DeclHandler events
>   must appear between the startDTD and endDTD events. Declarations are
>   assumed to belong to the internal DTD subset unless they appear
>   between startEntity and endEntity events. Comments and processing
>   instructions from the DTD should also be reported between the startDTD
>   and endDTD events, in their original order of (logical) occurrence;
>   they are not required to appear in their correct locations relative to
>   DTDHandler or DeclHandler events, however.
>
> Note that the start/endDTD events will appear within the
>   start/endDocument events from ContentHandler and before the first
>   startElement event.

However, you must also set the LexicalHandler for the XML Reader.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2;

public class Problem{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<!DOCTYPE html><hml><img/></hml>";
        SAXParser saxParser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
        InputSource in = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

        DefaultHandler2 myHandler = new DefaultHandler2(){
            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println("Element: " + qName);
            }

            @Override
            public void startDTD(String name,  String publicId,
            String systemId) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println("DocType: " + name);
            }
        };
        saxParser.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler",
                               myHandler);
        saxParser.parse(in, myHandler);
    }
}
```