# SAX parser does not call startDTD

Tags: java, sax, doctype

I have followed [Obtaining DOCTYPE details using SAX (JDK 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887764/obtaining-doctype-details-using-sax-jdk-7), implementing it like this:

```
public class MyXmlReader {

    public static void parse(InputSource inputSource) {
        try {
            XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();

            MyContentHandler handler = new MyContentHandler(); 
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
            xmlReader.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", handler);    // Does not work; handler is set, but startDTD/endDTD is not called
            xmlReader.setDTDHandler(handler);
            xmlReader.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
            xmlReader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
            xmlReader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
            xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            throw new MyImportException("Error while parsing file", e);
        }
    }
}
```

MyContentHandler extends DefaultHandler2, but neither startDTD nor endDTD is called (but e.g. startEntity is in fact called, so the lexical handler is set).
I have tried to leave the features out, but this changes nothing.

What goes wrong here?
I am using Java 8 JDK 1.8.0_144.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE MyMessage SYSTEM "http://www.testsite.org/mymessage/5.1/reference/international.dtd">
<MyMessage>
    <Header>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [XMLReader API](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html#setDTDHandler(org.xml.sax.DTDHandler)) you need to set a DTD Handler, otherwise DTD Events will be silently ignored. A `DefaultHandler2` yet implements DTDHandler interface, so you could use `xmlReader.setDTDHandler(handler);` again;

Comment: Could you please add an example XML? I verified your Java Snippet locally and startDTD was called. I used the following XML: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<img/>
</html>`

Comment: Example XML added.

Comment: Sorry, I cant help here. Your sample XML works on my machine. My handler callbacks look like `public void startDTD(String name, String publicId, String systemId)
  throws SAXException {
  System.out.println("start");
 }` I also have JDK 1.8.0_144 installed

Comment: Somehow it works now. And I cannot figure out why. Must have been a stupid mistake of mine of using the wrong code version or test data. Thanks.